# Quantile regression with transformation of response

Tags: quantile-regression, quantiles

> "A reference interval is a type of prediction interval and contains
>   the middle 95% of measurements of some substance or item from a
>   healthy population. Age specific reference intervals provide variable
>   interval limits based on age. An Age-Specific Reference Interval gives
>   the boundaries between which a typical measurement on an individual of
>   a certain age from a population of individuals is expected to fall.
>   The reference interval is often presented as percentiles of a healthy
>   reference population, such as the 2.5th percentile and the 97.5th
>   percentile".
>
> I have a dependent variable and variable Age as the independent
>   variable. I want to apply the nonparametirc quantile regression for
>   0.025 and 0.975 quantiles and I have this shape[image].

So I decided to use the power transformation method (calculated lambda=-0.37) for the dependent variable and work with the transformed variable.But I am not sure about the efficiency of this model to calculate the reference curve and the z score and predicted values. Should I remove the observations which are less than 0.5 in the second plot to have more smooth curve? What should I do when the nature of observation between 0 to one year old is completely different from 1 year to 19 years old?

[image]

[image]

Also this is the plot after using cubic root transformation.
[image]

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?  Your quantile regression appears to have succeeded.

Comment: You need a better title. It's not informative. Something like "Quantile regression with transformation of response" would work better.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the reply. It means you think I use the transformation method in a correct way and also the method for applying the quantile curves is chosen correctly?

Comment: @NickCox,  
thanks for the reply, I changed the title as you requested. I used power normal transformation and the calculated lambda is -0.37. Based on your advice I used the cube root (please see the final plot above). The nature of observation between 0 to 1 year is different from the rest of the observations. So any advice? I want to make the growth chart at 0.025 and 0.95 quantiles. The data set includes the information of kids from birth to 19 years old. Do you think that I should apply two different quantile regression for 0-1 year old and 1 year to 19 years old?

Comment: I don't know whether your regression is "correct": see Nick Cox's answer.  I am only pointing out that your question is unclear because it asks how to apply quantile regression, you applied it, and you got a result that is consistent with the data.  There's no information to determine whether that is meaningful, appropriate, or correct for your purposes.

Comment: @whuber, I just edited the question and provided more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is little or no detail here on the substantive, scientific or practical context but the following general or specific problems seem to be biting here:

- Calculating extreme percentiles requires an enormous sample size to work really well.
- Regression here and elsewhere can be sensitive to granularity in the data. Your transformation is unsatisfactory as you've **created** outliers from your smallest values. At a guess you're using something like log$_{10}$ (response + 0.5), but that maps zeros to a value much less than the next lowest value. A transformation such as log$_{10}$ (response + 1) or cube root is likely to work better.
- Whatever you're doing is not smoothing enough to make obvious sense as a solution. Does your smoothed curve make sense scientifically?
- Whatever you're dealing with clearly varies most within the first year of life, so it's not obvious that a linear scale for age is appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I changed the title as you requested. I used power normal transformation and the calculated lambda is -0.37. Based on your advice I used the cube root (please see the final plot above). The nature of observation between 0 to 1 year is different from the rest of the observations. So any advice? I want to make the growth chart at 0.025 and 0.95 quantiles

Comment: Cube roots do seem better than your previous transformation. I don't often find that Box-Cox (or whatever variant you're using) gives useful answers, despite the wonderful name and impressive theory. The answer to you question about age < and > 1 year I think requires specialist knowledge that I don't have. Even specialists would want to know what you're analysing. Your smoothed curves seem unacceptably erratic to this non-medic.